# rails model association author id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using rails_best_practices for linting my code.
Comments belong to post, which belongs to the user.
My `comments_controller.rb` file looks like this

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post

  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.create comment_params
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    redirect_to @post if @comment.save
  end

  private

    def find_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :body)
    end
end
```

And I'm getting this error `use model association (for @comment)`.
After refactoring my create method looks like this

```
def create
  @comment = @post.comments.create(
    comment_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  )
  redirect_to @post if @comment.save
end
```

My question is: What is the best and correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd suggest baking in any required parameters inside your controller-specific `_params` function. That is, do this:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :body).merge(
    user: current_user
  )
end
```

Then by the time it gets to your controller action you're pretty much good to go.

What I tend to do is have a `build` method that constructs the right object for both `new` and `create`:

```
def build_comment
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
end
```

Now this will correctly populate if you relax the `require` constraint on params, but it's up to you how to make that flexible. I find this consistently populates and prepares the same object for both multiple edit rounds, and the first round where you need to set some defaults.